# Can I solve the problem of html video tag

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm beginner Js Dev. I have some problem on HTML video tag by

1. I use style `display:none` for hide video tag
2. when user click button video tag will change to style `display:""` (I think video should show but It don't show)
3. when I have to minimize window, Video tag will show.

Someone help me to solve the problem please. I want to show video by user haven't minimize window

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what the html markup looks like?

Comment: Edit you question and added you line of code to it, we need more details and context to your question, we cant answer if we can see your code .